# How do I collapse rows of presence/absence data in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

Below is a simplified version of my dataframe.
It contains data about the presence (indicated with "1") and absence (indicated with "0") of various traits in various plant species.

```
Family <- c("Asteraceae", "Asteraceae", "Asteraceae", "Asteraceae", "Asteraceae", "Asteraceae", "Myrtaceae", "Myrtaceae", "Myrtaceae")
Species <- c("Senecio lautus", "Lactuca sativa", "Cynara cardunculus", "Helianthus annuus", "Helianthus tuberosus", "Smallanthus sonchifolius", "Eucalyptus pauciflora", "Eucalyptus regnans", "Corymbia maculata")
Trait1 <- c(1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0)
Trait2 <- c(0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1)
Trait3 <- c(0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0)
dataframe1 <- data.frame(Family, Species, Trait1, Trait2, Trait3)

dataframe1
      Family                  Species Trait1 Trait2 Trait3
1 Asteraceae           Senecio lautus      1      0      0
2 Asteraceae           Lactuca sativa      1      0      0
3 Asteraceae       Cynara cardunculus      0      1      1
4 Asteraceae        Helianthus annuus      1      1      1
5 Asteraceae     Helianthus tuberosus      0      1      0
6 Asteraceae Smallanthus sonchifolius      1      0      1
7  Myrtaceae    Eucalyptus pauciflora      0      0      0
8  Myrtaceae       Eucalyptus regnans      0      1      0
9  Myrtaceae        Corymbia maculata      0      1      0
```

I would like to summarise this data for each family to have the number of species per family in my data, and the presence of traits, resulting in the following data frame:

```
      Family        Number of Species  Trait1  Trait2  Trait3
1 Asteraceae                        6       1       1       1
2  Myrtaceae                        3       0       1       0
```

Comment: How do you have `Trait1` as 1 for "Asteraceae" ? It is present in 4 `Species`.

Comment: @RonakShah In the second data frame, the value if 1 for Trait1 in Asteraceae is an indication of the presence of Trait1 in any Asteraceae species, rather than a count of the number of species with Trait1 (i.e., 4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After grouping by 'Family', get the number of observations (`n()` as 'Number_of_species'), loop `across` the 'Trait', columns check for `any` TRUE values (after converting to `logical`) or use `+(1 %in% .)` or `+(. > 0)`

```
library(dplyr)
dataframe1 %>% 
   group_by(Family) %>%
   summarise(Number_of_species = n(),
      across(starts_with('Trait'), ~ +(any(as.logical(.)))), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 5
#  Family     Number_of_species Trait1 Trait2 Trait3
#  <chr>                  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
#1 Asteraceae                 6      1      1      1
#2 Myrtaceae                  3      0      1      0
```

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` option

```
setDT(dataframe1)[, c(.(Species = .N), +(colSums(.SD) > 0)), Family, .SDcols = patterns("^Trait")]
```

gives

```
       Family Species Trait1 Trait2 Trait3
1: Asteraceae       6      1      1      1
2:  Myrtaceae       3      0      1      0
```