# How do I collapse and summarise columns of presence-absence data in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I used the `summarise` function from *dplyr* to collapse rows in this way (using answers from [How do I collapse rows of presence/absence data in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65766248/how-do-i-collapse-rows-of-presence-absence-data-in-r)), but I am unsure how to do the same thing for columns.

I currently have:

```
    Species Leaf.trait.1 Leaf.trait.2 Leaf.trait.3 Flower.trait.1 Flower.trait.2
1 Species 1            0            1            0              0              0
2 Species 2            0            1            0              0              0
3 Species 3            1            1            0              0              0
4 Species 4            1            0            1              0              1
5 Species 5            0            0            1              1              1
6 Species 6            1            1            0              1              0
```

I would like to make:

```
    Species  Leaf.traits  Flower.traits
1 Species 1            1              0
2 Species 2            1              0
3 Species 3            1              0
4 Species 4            1              1
5 Species 5            1              1
6 Species 6            1              1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) dplyr** Use `c_across` twice:

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>% 
  rowwise %>%
  transmute(Species, 
            Leaf.traits = max(c_across(starts_with("Leaf"))), 
            Flower.traits = max(c_across(starts_with("Flower")))) %>%
  ungroup
```

**2) tidyr** If this was just an example and in reality there are many groups of columns then pivot to long form perform the summarization and pivot back.  file_path_sans_ext from tools (which comes with R so it does not have to be installed) removes the suffix from its character argument.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tools)

DF %>%
 pivot_longer(-Species) %>%
 group_by(Species, name = file_path_sans_ext(name)) %>%
 summarize(value = max(value)) %>%
 ungroup %>%
 pivot_wider
```

### Note

```
DF <- structure(list(Species = c("Species 1", "Species 2", "Species 3", 
"Species 4", "Species 5", "Species 6"), Leaf.trait.1 = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), Leaf.trait.2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), 
    Leaf.trait.3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), Flower.trait.1 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), Flower.trait.2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
    0L)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), 
    class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the dataframe based on similar column names using `split.default` and find rowwise maximum in each group.

```
cbind(df[1], sapply(split.default(df[-1], 
      sub('\\.\\d+$', '', names(df)[-1])), function(x) do.call(pmax, x)))

#   Species Flower.trait Leaf.trait
#1 Species1            0          1
#2 Species2            0          1
#3 Species3            0          1
#4 Species4            1          1
#5 Species5            1          1
#6 Species6            1          1
```

where `-1` is to ignore the `Species` column and `sub` is used to remove the number at the last.

```
sub('\\.\\d+$', '', names(df)[-1])
#[1] "Leaf.trait"   "Leaf.trait"   "Leaf.trait"   "Flower.trait" "Flower.trait"
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Species = c("Species1", "Species2", "Species3", 
"Species4", "Species5", "Species6"), Leaf.trait.1 = c(0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), Leaf.trait.2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Leaf.trait.3 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), Flower.trait.1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L
), Flower.trait.2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution

```r
df <- structure(list(Species = c("Species 1", "Species 2", "Species 3", 
                                 "Species 4", "Species 5", "Species 6"), Leaf.trait.1 = c(0L, 
                                                                                          0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), Leaf.trait.2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), 
                     Leaf.trait.3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), Flower.trait.1 = c(0L, 
                                                                                  0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), Flower.trait.2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                          0L)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), 
                class = "data.frame")
library(tidyverse)

pivot_longer(
  data = df, 
  cols = -Species, 
  names_to = c(".value", "set"), 
  names_pattern = "(.+)\\.(\\d+)"
) %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(across(ends_with("trait"), max, na.rm = T))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   Species   Leaf.trait Flower.trait
#>   <chr>          <int>        <int>
#> 1 Species 1          1            0
#> 2 Species 2          1            0
#> 3 Species 3          1            0
#> 4 Species 4          1            1
#> 5 Species 5          1            1
#> 6 Species 6          1            1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>